# Value of a fraction

Tags: fractions

It it true that  is ${a^2+c^2\over b^2+d^2}=1$ for $ad-bc=1$?

I tried substituting in $a={1-bc\over d}$ but it is still a mess.

(How do you ask Wolfram Alpha a question like this where we ask it to calculate something with an imposed condition?)

Comment: Take $a = 2$ and $b = c = d = 1$.

Comment: What is true is that $(a^2+c^2)(b^2+d^2)=(ad-bc)^2+(ab+cd)^2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true. Try it for $a = 2$ and $b = c = d = 1$:

$$
ad - bc = 2\times1 - 1\times1 = 1
$$

$$
\frac{a^2+c^2}{b^2+d^2} = \frac{2^2+1^2}{1^2+1^2} = \frac{5}{2} \ne 1
$$

As for WA, you can use the `FullSimplify` function to simplify an expression given some assumptions. Here is an [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5Ba%5E2%20%2b%202ab%20%2b%20b%5E2,%20a%20%2b%20b%20==%202%5D).

Comment: Or even simpler: $b=c=0$, so $a={1 \over d}$ and ${{a^2+c^2}\over {b^2+d^2}}={{a^2} \over {d^2}} = {1 \over {d^4}}$